# VScode - pylance doesn't identify the error correctly while Jedi doesn't mark the error correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylance

I am newbie to VS code. I am using only one version of Python - Python 3. I did the installation and configuration for python and I find the error identification and underlining is not working correctly.

Example:
I removed the parenthesis of print -
[image: pylance underlines the text of the print statement and not the print]

Pylance doesnt underline the print statement but the text inside. This annoying and I would like the red underlining to be under the print which would help a newbie to understand where the problem exactly is. The worst part is the error pointed out is completely different - "Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons" and there are no 'quick fixes.

While I am seen it point to the correct errors both positionally and semantically, I don't know what the setting to get that is -

[image]

The above is what I want. Where it underlines correctly and gives the correct solution also.

**What I tried:**

I tried meddling with the settings.json. I tried setting the language server to 'none' but that gave me a different result -
[image]

While the error is pointed out in the Problems window below, the print part is not underlined and if I hover over the underline it shows only the description of the print statement.

Then I tried setting `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"`. Still no luck.
[image]

I would be immensely grateful for any help.

Comment: there is Nothing wrong with `print` it is a known variable, the parser has problems with the string, not allowed there, so it flags the string

Comment: The correct syntax is print("text") in Python 3. Why is it showing that in the second pic then?

Comment: you can do other things with `print` than call, for the compiler it is not special, it is just a variable that is callable

Comment: i agree. But how do I get it to function like it did in the second pic?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable or disable **linter** and change their options. Enabling **linter** is documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters), Pylint options are documented [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/options.html), and Pylance options are documented [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).

But, there won't be any magic setting that will make the errors and underlines better.  If there *was* a nicer error message in Pylance/Pylint, or a more accurate underline, it would be the default: there's no setting on your side that will change that. Making Python errors more understandable is VERY hard and something only a cython developer can do (they did in Python 3.10) or the person writing the linter you integrated in VS Code can do.

So you can also open an issue at [pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues) or [pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/) so they address the issue you're having.